# Finding limit without using L'Hopital rule

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

How to prove $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac {\ln(x)}{x}=0$$ without using L'Hospital Rule. Just by using some basis limit properties.

Comment: I wonder how many times this has been asked here...

Answer (score 2):

For sufficiently large $x$:$0\le \ln (x)\le \sqrt x$. Now divide by $x$ and squeeze.

Comment: How about for lim x-> 0 x.ln(x)??

Comment: how about you do your own homework?

Comment: That escalated quickly

Comment: @IttayWeiss Lol .@aavatar log function grow very slowly so that is why limit i zero .u can write inequalities for urself

Answer (score 0):

set $$x=e^t ,t\rightarrow \infty $$so now 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac
{ln(x)}{x}=\\\lim_{t\rightarrow +\infty }\frac
{ln(e^t)}{e^t}=\\\lim_{t\rightarrow +\infty }\frac
{t}{e^t}=\\\\\lim_{t\rightarrow +\infty }\frac
{t}{1+t+\frac{t^2}{2!}+\frac{t^3}{3!}+\frac{t^4}{4!}+....}=\\$$ obviously the limit go to zero

Comment: i got lim t -> infinity t/(e^t). What now?? please...

Comment: estimate $e^t$ by some of the first terms of the taylor series. You should be able to obtain an estimate of the form $0\leq t/e^t\leq c/t^\alpha$ for some $\alpha\geq 1$, $c>0$ and $t$ large enough.

Answer (score -1):

The Taylor series for $\ln(x)$ in $-1\le x \le 1$ is given by :

[image]

You can substitute this and then apply the basic limits results to get the answer.

Comment: Without l'Hospital's rule, but with Taylor series?!